# Show gone view in Android Studio in preview

Tags: android, view, android-studio

I don't want set visibility programmatically and I make it in xml files, but when I set visibility property to GONE view hides from preview screen. Sometimes I need to correct some field in gone views and I must change visibility to VISIBLE, make changes and change visibility back. It's annoying.

How to make view with visibility GONE visible ONLY in Android Studio preview.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is indeed a simple way to do that:

- Define the `tools` attribute in your main Layout:

  ```
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  ```
- Use it to make your element visible, like you normally would:

  ```
  tools:visibility="visible"
  ```